# Updating Collection in EF Code First

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have an issue mapping a Model with Entity Framework by Code-First, This is a short version of my model:

```
public class Project
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ProjectPolicies Policies { get; set; }
    public int ProjectPoliciesId { get; set; }
}

public class ProjectPolicies
{
    public int ProjectPoliciesId { get; set; }
    public DemographicInformation DemographicInformation { get; set; }
    public int DemographicInformationId { get; set; }
}

public class DemographicInformation
{
    public int DemographicInformationId { get; set; }
    public virtual List<DemographicItem> Items { get; set; }
}

public class DemographicItem
{
    public int DemographicItemId { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public DemographicValueType Type { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public DemographicInformation DemographicInformation { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to add a new DemographicItem:

```
var project = this.myDbContext.Projects.Where(p => p.ProjectId.Equals(id)).First();

project.ProjectPolicies.DemographicInformation.DemographicItems.Add(item);
this.myRepository.Entry<Project>(project);
this.myDbContext.SaveChanges();
```

It does not work, because it creates a new row into the database table DemographicInformations instead of updating the existing one; I've tried to add navigation properties to different entity levels but again it does not work. Is there a way to map this DemographicItem collection from Project Entity?

**UPDATE:** Thanks Gert Arnold but it did not work, after adding a new item into the DemographicItems the correspondent table into the database is filled with a new row and new Id. but this new entry has empty items.

Comment: Hi, it's only now that I happen to see your update. It's better to add such comments to answers because then the answerer will receive a notification.

Answer (score 0):

You should load the `DemographicInformation` and its `Item`s

```
var project = this.myDbContext.Projects
              .Include(p=>p.Policies.Select(x=>x.DemographicInformation.Items))
              .Where(p => p.ProjectId.Equals(id)).First();
```

because `ProjectPolicies.DemographicInformation` is not lazy loading (it's not `virtual`). So EF does not see it as an existing object.

Or you must add the `virtual`modifier to make it lazy loading (not that that will fire a second query after the `Frist()`).

Comment: Thanks Gert Arnold but it did not work, after adding a new item into the DemographicItems the correspondent table into the database is filled with a new row and new Id. but this new entry has empty items.